# Jquery click in on click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some strange behaviour with the jquery click event. This was my code:

```
$("#item").on("click",function(){
    //do some stuff
    $("#item2").click(); // doesn't work!
});
```

But the second click is not working when clicking #item. When manually clicking item2 it does work. I got it to work when doing this:

```
$("#item").on("click",function(){
    //do some stuff
    document.getElementById("item2").click(); //WORKS!
});
```

I also tried `event.preventDefault()` before the jquery click trigger but that doesn't work either.

Can somebody explain why this doesn't work with jquery?

Comment: try `$("#item2").trigger('click');`

Comment: Did your maybe add the #item in your HTML by script?

Comment: `$("#item2").trigger( "click" );` --> see : http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `click()` as a simple method, it must be a function, so you should `trigger()` the click event:

```
$("#item").on("click",function(){
    //do some stuff
    $("#item2").trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
    $("#item").on("click",function(){
        //do some stuff
        $("#item2").trigger('click'); // Now Works !!!
     });

    $("#item2").on("click",function(){
        //do some stuff
     alert('working')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="item">item1</button><button id="item2">item1</button>
```

please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cUbC/26/).
I have added

```
$("#item2").trigger('click');
```

in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

`$("#item2").trigger('click');` // use trigger function of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation of JQuery? in https://api.jquery.com/click/ there explained aout onClick, and you can find why `event.preventDefault` doesn't work before the JQuery Trigger

For Solution :

```
$("#item2").trigger('click'); // Use trigger function of jQuery to Trigger
```

Please Read the Documentation